# SQL CE not loading from network share

Tags: sql-server-ce

I installed VS 2010 RC yesterday, and suddenly, SQL Server CE isn't loading files from a network share. In projects compiled with VS 2008, if I try to open a SQL CE file located on a network share, I get an error that reads like this:

*Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.*

If I try to create a data connection in VS 2010 to a SQL CE file on a network share, I get this error:

*SQL Server Compact does not support opening database files on a network share.*

Can anyone shed any light on what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they fixed that 'problem'  :)  Why are you not use SQL Express at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Compact is a single user, in-process database engine, for network based databases, use the free SQL Server Express.

Comment: I'll accept that answer, but reluctantly. While my app is single-user, and is designed for use with an in-process database, it is possible that a user might want to store a data file on a network share. Up until very recently, SQL CE supported that configuration. It appears that MS has disabled that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft added the artificial error "SQL Server Compact does not support opening database files on a network share" to the tools built into Visual Studio.  You will need to use other tools to access SQL Server Compact files on the network.  They will work without that error as it (the error message) does not come from the OLEDB driver.  Note that saying "SQL Compact is a single user, in-process database engine, for network based databases" completely contradicts "SQL Server Compact does not support opening database files on a network share".

One such tool is available at the following site and it works within Visual Studio.
http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/